# Compile error for NReports using Monodevelop in Ubuntu

Tags: compiler-errors, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to compile the [NReports](http://nreports.codeplex.com/) project in Ubuntu 12.04 using Monodevelop but it fails with the following error:

```
Tool /usr/local/bin/resgen2 execution started with arguments: /useSourcePath /compile "RdlDesigner.resx,obj/Debug/NReports.RdlDesign.RdlDesigner.resources" 
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Tool exited with code: 1. Output: Error: Invalid ResX input.
Position: Line 139, Column 5.
Inner exception: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
```

Here are my configurations:

- Mono 3.2.3
- Monodevelop 4.1.7
- NReports 0.8.2

How can I overcome this problem?